# Can't access global array in ARC enable project

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, global-variables, automatic-ref-counting

I have define NSArray using

```
extern NSArray *arName;
```

in AppDelegate method

and then assign values in Array in AppDelegate. after assign value i easily access values in AppDelegate but when I use this global array in another page control it's shows me error

i don't know the exact problem

is it any other method to define GLOBAL ARRAY ?

Comment: i get EXE_BAD_ACCESS. sometimes i get lower count value of array

Comment: The error is the system's way of saying "AAAARRRRGHHHH! Don't use global variables".

Comment: Why we cannot use global variables in ARC?

Comment: @NuzhatZari You just shouldn't use global variable at all. Ever. Regardless of whether you are using ARC or not.

Comment: @NickBull i have used BOOL global variable and it's work perfect but don't know what's the matter with ARRAY

Comment: @CocoaMatters I'm not saying that you can't get it to work. I'm just saying that you SHOULDN'T use it. It's poor design and can lead to many problems (including the one you are experiencing). Just because you had it working for the situation you had previously doesn't mean that wasn't just down to pure luck.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off in this case using a singleton Objective-C class. Don't use global variables with anything that is derived from NSObject, or the ARC system is unable to automatically keep track of references to the object and you'll get crashes like these.

Comment: Plus global variables are just a sign of poor design.